# Search bar is Not working in flatlist React Native...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I'm being struggling a couple of days with search bar in my app, the problem is that when I search with particular name of products the products with that name show up but when I clear the search bar the entire products disappear not showing up after clearing search bar?

Here is my Code:

```
 const Home =()=>{

  // State
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryData)
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null)
  const [productst, setProducts] = useState (ProductData)
   
 
  // seach function 
     function handleSearch(text){

        const filterData = productst.filter((item)=>{
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
       })

       setProducts(filterData)

     }

    function renederHeader(){

   return(
         
         //Search Input 
            <View style={{ marginTop:SIZES.margin,}} >
                <TouchableOpacity 
                     onPress={()=>{}} 
                     style={{
                          flexDirection:'row',
                          alignSelf:'center',
                      }}>
                    <TextInput 
                      placeholder=" Find Your Favourite..."
                      placeholderTextColor={COLORS.lightGrey20}
                     // value={}
                      onChangeText={text=>handleSearch(text)}
                     
                    />
                     
            </TouchableOpacity>
                 </View>


}



  function renderCategories(){
      return(
        <View
           style={{
            marginTop:20,
           }}
        >
            <FlatList 
              horizontal
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              data={categories}
              keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
              renderItem={({item,index})=>{
                return(
                  <TouchableOpacity  
                     onPress={()=>onSelecteCategory(item)}>
)
```

My Product Data:

```
 export const ProductData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name:'Coffee',
      categories: [1],
      image: require('../asset/images/coffee1.png'),
      index: 0,
      },
 {
      id: 2,
      name:'Coffee',
      categories: [1],
      image: require('../asset/images/coffee2.png'),
      index: 0,
      },
 {
      id: 3,
      name:'Coffee',
      categories: [1],
      image: require('../asset/images/coffee3.png'),
      index: 0,
      },
 {
      id: 4,
      name:'Tea',
      categories: [2],
      image: require('../asset/images/Tea1.png'),
      index: 0,
      }, {
      id: 5,
      name:'Tea',
      categories: [2],
      image: require('../asset/images/Tea2.png'),
      index: 0,
      },
      {
      id: 6,
      name:'Tea',
      categories: [2],
      image: require('../asset/images/Tea3.png'),
      index: 0,
      },

 {
      id: 7,
      name:'choclate',
      categories: [3],
      image: require('../asset/images/choclate1.png'),
      index: 0,
      },

{
      id: 8,
      name:'choclate',
      categories: [3],
      image: require('../asset/images/choclate2.png'),
      index: 0,
      },
{
      id: 9,
      name:'choclate',
      categories: [3],
      image: require('../asset/images/choclate3.png'),
      index: 0,
      },


]
```

So, Please if anyone can help me how to search in bar and get the certain products and when I clear the search bar the all products should show up normally not disappear as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler function takes the state variable products as input for the filter. Therefore the array of possible values decreases with every iteration of filtering, even when the input is deleted.

Try to instead use the product data array as input. This will cause the filter to always look at the whole dataset, whenever the input changes.

Comment: Can you please edit and correct the handler function how to be if you don't mind in code? what kind or input should I use

Comment: I am on mobile unfortunately, but basically inside the handler function replace productst with ProductData

Comment: Bro, you are awesome , it is working as I'm expecting I don't know how to thank you. thank you so so much